# Waiting until text to be present in element is NOT the string provided

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, expected-condition

I'm looking for a way to have selenium webdriver wait until the text present in the element location I'm interested is NOT the string provided in the code below.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"order-details\"]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[1]/div"),"Completed successfully"));
```

I'm looking for a way where the "text to be present" is not "Completed successfully" so that the code can move forward and no longer wait

Comment: Do you want to wait till the text **Completed successfully** is removed from the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [ExpectedConditions - not](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"order-details\"]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[1]/div"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, "Completed successfully")));
```