# Selenium: wait until text NOT to be present in element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to extract the article titles from a webpage with a multi-page list of articles.

I get the article titles on the first page using:

```
titles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(r'path')
for i in range(len(titles)):
    titles_list.append(titles[i].text)
```

I navigate to the next page using:

```
next_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath(r'path')
next_page.click()
```

Then, I return to the first step (i.e. getting the article titles).

---

The problem is, using the codes above, I sometimes get the article titles of a page twice and I sometimes miss the article titles of a page.

I believe the solution is to wait until the page fully loads after the second step and before repeating the first step: I should store something unique to the first page (e.g. the first article's title) in a variable (e.g. 'first_item'), and I should wait until the corresponding element does not contain that text.

---

I found the answer to my question but in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101845/waiting-until-text-to-be-present-in-element-is-not-the-string-provided) which used `ExpectedConditions.not`, but the following code (the `EC.not()` part) is not valid in Python and raise a SyntaxError:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

next_page.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, r'path'), first_item)))
```

How can I wait until a text is not present in an element in Python?

Comment: Would you please mention the URL and your code so the problem can be solved easily

Comment: Can you provide HTML code?

Answer (score 4):

You Can wait like this

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until_not(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'xpath')))

while element == True:
    try:
        element.click()
    except:
        pass
```

However it is weird looking but It will wait until the element is found else loop will continue

Comment: The problem was the element names were the same (only the content changes) and they were always clickable (even before the contact change is complete), so I was still getting the wrong results using `EC.element_to_be_clickable()`. The `.until_not()` solved my problem!